# Getting timeout error while trying fetch the text of a toast alert

Tags: angularjs, protractor

Toast alert DOM Structure:

```html
<uib-alert id="alert-message-0" class="cs-toast-alert ng-binding ng-scope" ng-repeat="alert in headerModel.alerts()" type="success"
close="" ng-style="{bottom: (((headerModel.alerts().length - $index ) * 70) - 48) + 'px'}" 
ng-bind-html="headerModel.trustAsHtml(alert.msg)" style="bottom: 22px;">Successfully completed discharge</uib-alert>
```

Method used is:

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
            browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(element(by.id("alert-message-0"))),8000).then(function () {
                return element(by.id('alert-message-0')).getAttribute('innerText').then(function (ttmessage) {
                    expect(ttmessage).toContain('Successfully completed discharge');
                    //browser.ignoreSynchronization = false;
                });
            });
```

Getting Error:
 - Failed: Wait timed out after 8856ms

Answer (score 0):

Try that:

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(element(by.id('alert-message-0'))), 8000);
return expect(element(by.id('alert-message-0')).getText()).to.eventually.equals('Successfully completed discharge');
```

Comment: Thanks first of all.     Tried with the option you suggested receiving error  Failed: Cannot read property 'eventually' of undefined

Comment: change last line to: `return expect(element(by.css('uib-alert')).getText()).to.eventually.equals('Successfully completed discharge');`